# How can I add a run configuration for webpack in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webstorm

I've tried creating one using the Node.js configuration but when I try to run it, I get:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'c:\dev\github\react-examples\webpack'
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work? I'd rather just use WebStorm's GUI to run webpack instead of having to open the console each time and writing `webpack -w` manually every time

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add webpack script to package.json and create NPM run configuration:

[image: npm configuration for webpack]